# Is there any way to return a custom error on permission_callback in WordPress REST API

Tags: json, wordpress-rest-api

I have registered route with this code

```
register_rest_route(
            "v1/senders",
            "read",
            [
                "methods"             => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
                "callback"            => [
                    new Sender(),
                    "read"
                ],
                "permission_callback" => function ( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
                    return /* Function returning true/false */;
                }
            ]
        );
```

I got this message when permission callback function return **false**:

```
{
    "code": "rest_forbidden",
    "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to do that.",
        "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```

Is there any way to customize this message - hook, filter, etc.? I use a different data format on frontend for successfull responses, so I need to modify these responses too. Thanks in advance for any reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to accomplish:

```
register_rest_route(
        "v1/senders",
        "read",
        [
            "methods"             => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
            "callback"            => [
                new Sender(),
                "read"
            ],
            "permission_callback" => function ( $request ) {
                //Function returning true/false/WP_Error;
                if( YES ){ //-->your custom permission condition!
                    return true;
                }else{
                    //Modify the below message and/or status code if you want!
                    return new WP_Error(
                        'rest_forbidden',
                        __( 'Sorry, you are not allowed to do that!!!.' ),
                        array( 'status' => rest_authorization_required_code() )
                    );
                }
            }
        ]
    );
```

Comment: The result will be the same JSON object, but I needed WordPress to return my own JSON object structure on error. Sorry for unclear question. But, to be honest, your answer is exact answer on question what I asked, but not the one I've expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
"permission_callback" => function ( $request ) {
     return new \WP_Error(
         'rest_cannot_view',
         __( 'Sorry, you cannot list resources.' ),
         array( 'status' => rest_authorization_required_code() ));
}
```